# Unit-testing a service that uses the EntityManagerInterface in Symfony 3.3

Tags: symfony, doctrine, phpunit

I have a service that uses the EntityManagerInterface:

```
class DocFinderService
{
   protected $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
   {
     $this->em = $entityManager;
   }

  public function findDocs($specialtyCodes, $city, $state, $zip)
  {...}
```

How can I test the service using PHPUnit, specifically, how can I pass the *EntityManagerInterface* parameter from the test function?

Answer (score 1):

When you writing a Unit test, I mean true UNIT-test (you can use PHPUnit for functional test also), you must always ask yourself what you want to test.

Do you want to test `EntityManager`? The answer is NO. More than that - your test should pass even if `EntityManager` stops working properly for some fantastic reason.

So you must use mock of `EntityManager`. Please check docs for more details https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test-doubles.html#mock-objects

The contents of mock depends on code of your `findDocs` method. As soon as it is *find* function, I think you must test that `findDocs` returns some data if ORM layer is able to find something and returns null (or empty array or throws Exception) if no data is found by ORM layer.

```
class DocFinderService extends TestCase {

        public function testFound() {
            /** @var EntityManagerInterface | MockObject $entityManager */
            $entityManager = $this->createMock(EntityManagerInterface::class);

            /** @var ObjectRepository | MockObject $repo */
            $repo = $this->createMock(ObjectRepository::class);
            $repo->expects($this->once())->method('findBy')->willReturn([new DocEntity('doc_id_1'), new DocEntity('doc_id_2')]);
            $entityManager->expects($this->once())->method('getRepository')->willReturn($repo);

            $docFinder = new DocFinderService($entityManager);
            $result = $docFinder->findDocs('SOME_SPECILAITY_CODE', 'City', 'State', 'ZIP');
            $this->assertTrue(is_array($result));
            $this->assertCount(2, $result);
        }

        public function testNotFound() {
            /** @var EntityManagerInterface | MockObject $entityManager */
            $entityManager = $this->createMock(EntityManagerInterface::class);

            /** @var ObjectRepository | MockObject $repo */
            $repo = $this->createMock(ObjectRepository::class);
            $repo->expects($this->once())->method('findBy')->willReturn(null);
            $entityManager->expects($this->once())->method('getRepository')->willReturn($repo);

            $docFinder = new DocFinderService($entityManager);
            $result = $docFinder->findDocs('SOME_SPECILAITY_CODE', 'City', 'State', 'ZIP');
            $this->assertNull(result);
        }
    }
```

I've also added mock of `ObjectRepository`, it's supposed that in your code you'll be use it for enity fetching. You may use `QueryBuilder` or some other ways for same purpose.

That was completely about "true" Unit-tests. If you want to use real `EntityManager` with some testing environment, in that case you'll need to initialize your app or some part of app which effects on ORM layer with testing environment parameters. But it is another long story

Answer (score 0):

You can mock it as you would anything else, and have any calls on it tested like you would another object.

For example, here's a snippet of where I use a library called Mockery (aliased as 'm::') and tell it that I expect `flush()` should be called.

```
$em = m::mock(EntityManagerInterface::class);
$em->shouldReceive('flush');

$this->whc = new WebhookController($this->log, $this->eventDispatcher, $em);
```

How complex your mocks/stubs need to be depends on your code, and how testable it is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do, but if what you want to do is load in a phpunit all the classes you need with dependency injection the test code should look like this:

```
//make sure your test extends of 'KernelTestCase' and not 'TestCase'
class MyTest extends KernelTestCase
{
  /**
   * @var DocFinderService
   */
  private $docFinderService;

  protected function setUp(): void
  {
    // Initializing symfony's kernel
    self::bootKernel();

    // getting the application
    $application = new \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application(self::$kernel);
    $this->docFinderService = self::$container->get(DocFinderService::class);
  }

  public function testExecute(): void
  {
     // here you can use $docFinderService
     $this->findDocs(...);
  }
}
```